How can I remove this notched aerator?
I am trying to remove the aerator from my faucet. I tried two aerator keys but none of them worked. Do I need to remove the whole faucet to replace it?

[

When you say that none of the keys worked, did they not fit, or did they not turn the aerator?  If they fit, but didn't turn the aerator, my guess is that there has been mineral buildup in the threads, making it difficult to turn.
What I would suggest doing to try and clean up some of those minerals is to take a small bag with some vinegar and then put the bag underneath the spout for a few hours/days with the aerator soaking in the vinegar in hopes that will dissolve enough of the minerals to loosen it up enough to turn.
Also check to make sure you're trying to loosen it the right way and not accidentally tightening it.

Thank you for your answer. I don't think none of them fit., since it does not have thread on it. I tried the plastic one and metal one. I think the faucet might needs to be disassembled to replace it. Thanks.
